# How to put a random integer into a table in HTML and js

Tags: javascript, html, math

I need a random integer in a table in HTML, and have the correct code but it doesn't work for some reason! Here is my code so far:

```
document.getElementById(Example).innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;
```

My error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhR8X.jpg
My code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji2lL.jpg

Comment: It needs to be `'Example'` or `"Example"`, not just `Example`.

Comment: @CodeF0x this still has not fixed my problem

Comment: Does `getElementById()` find the element? Any errors in your browser's dev console? (When you press F12 and head to "Console")

Comment: Can you post your html ?

Comment: @CodeF0x there is an error message saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at Index.html:7

Comment: yes look at @tiagos answer

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức ok

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức it won't let me

Comment: Okay, that means that `getElementById()` can't find the element. Is your id typed correctly? On the `id` attribute of your element **and** on the script? At what section of your document is the script placed? In the head? In the body? At the end of the body? Can you show us your HTML too, please?

Comment: we can not help you if you do not give us any hint of your html code

Comment: @rvz I'm trying to upload a pic of it now

Comment: just copy us your html code

Comment: I have posted a pic of my html

Comment: Hope that helps

Comment: From your HTML code, it looks like the script is executed before the element even exists in the DOM. Try to put the script at the very bottom of your body.

Comment: Glad to help! And don't worry, everyone stumbled upon this at least once when doing webdevelopment ;).

Answer (score 3):

If you assign your table cell a valid ID, your code should work:

```js
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="example"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must have something like this.

As the CodeF0x spoke, you have to have `'example'` or `"example"` in the id when you fetch the element

```js
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your html tag is `<input type='text' id='example'/>`

```
document.getElementById("example").value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;
```

if your html tag is `<td id='example'></td>`

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;
```

```js
document.getElementById("example").value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;

document.getElementById("exampleTd").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;
```

```html
<input type='text' id='example'/>

<table>
  <tr><td id='exampleTd'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the code you have to generate a random number.

```js
var cell = document.getElementById('random');

cell.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td id="random">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID should be quoted if you are using it directly or you can put it in a variable and use it that way:

```
document.getElementById('Example').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;

var a='answers-header';
document.getElementById(a).innerHTML=Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with list

```
<body>
 <ul id="myList">

 </ul>

 <button id="btn" onclick="addRandomNumber()">Add number</button>
</body>
```

Script

```
   function addRandomNumber(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;

    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(randomNum);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

typeError :Cannot set property "innerHtml" of null

it can not find your element "Example" Because you write script before Html tag

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("pointsA1").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)  + 1;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>England</td>
    <td id="pointsA1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```